# Xamarin Forms button text binding fail

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I am trying to bind a string to the button text.

This is my viewmodel.

```
public class MainPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private IUserDialogs _dialog;
    private const string START = "Start";
    private const string STOP = "Stop";

    public ICommand Start { get; }
    public string startText { get; set; }

    public MainPageViewModel(IUserDialogs dialogManager)
    {
        _dialog = dialogManager;
        Start = new Command(()=>toggleStart());
        startText = START;
    }

    private void toggleStart()
    {
        if(startText.Equals(START))
        {
            startText = STOP;
            _dialog.Toast("Start Monitoring");
        }
        else if (startText.Equals(STOP))
        {
            startText = START;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my xaml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ble.net.sampleapp.view.MainPage"
             Title="Monitor">
    <RelativeLayout>
        <Button Text="{Binding startText}"
                Command="{Binding Start}"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I want to let the button text change between Start and Stop as I press it. However, it shows Start initially and would not change when I press it. I have tested the command binding work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order the view to take into account the change of `startText` you have to notify the change of that property. [Here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/) it explains `PropertyChanged` and some implementations.

I'm not quite sure what is your `BaseViewModel` but I imagine that it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. So in the setter of your property you have to call `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));`, i.e.:

```
private string _startText;
public string StartText
{
    get => this._startText;
    set
    {
        this._startText;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(StartText)));
    }
}
```

and with that your View will be notified to update its value when `PropertyChanged` is raised.

Obviously it can be improved by having a method that invokes the event with the name of the property.

Also you can use [Fody.PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) to automagically raise PropertyChanged in the public properties of your ViewModels.

HIH